# The best way to execute JavaScript code in Dart Flutter project iOS/Android/Web

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I need execute part of JS code and give output back to Dart code.
I try use `flutter_js: ^0.5.0+6` and it is working in iOS/Android, but I can't compile web project.
How I can execute code like this?

```dart
   String jsResult = javascriptRuntime.evaluate("""
            if (typeof MyClass == 'undefined') {
              var MyClass = class  {
                constructor(id) {
                  this.id = id;
                }
                
                getId() { 
                  return this.id;
                }
              }
            }
            var obj = new MyClass(1);
            var jsonStringified = JSON.stringify(obj);
            var value = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 100).toString();
            JSON.stringify({ "object": jsonStringified, "expression": value});
            """).stringResult;
```

(this is sample code from flutter_js: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js/example )

I need build app for iOS/Android/Web. Actually working on `Flutter 2.10.3`.